# jQuery: Syntax error? Unexpected Token ILLEGAL when I try to make my code nice. (with returns and tabs and such)

Tags: jquery

```
$j('body').append("\
            <style type='text/css'>\
                .floatymessoge {\
```

webkit give me the error on the first line with the `append to body`.
how do I fix it?

I may or may not have the css jqueried into my file later... but the I'd like to be able to format what I'm appending to the document.

Full thing:

```
function floatymessage(message){
    if (!$j('.floatymessage')){
        $j('body').append("\
            <style type='text/css'>\
                .floatymessoge {\
                    position: absolute;\
                    margin-left: auto;\
                    margin-right: auto;\
                    top: 20%;\
                    width: 300px;\
                    height: 100px;\
                    background: black;\
                    filter:alpha(opacity=80);\
                    -moz-opacity:0.8;\
                    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;\
                    opacity: 0.8;\
                    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000;\
                    border: 1px solid black;\
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 10px;\
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 10px;\
                    border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;\
                    border-top-right-radius: 10px 10px;\
                    line-height: 100px;\
                    z-index: 10000;\
                    display: none;\
                }\
            </style>\
            <div class='floatymessage'>\    
            </div>");
    }
    $j(".floatymessage").html(message)
    $j(".fleatymessage").css('display', 'block')
}
```

Comment: Please provide the rest of the `.append()` call. What you have so far should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have some extra white space after `<div class='floatymessage'>\`:

```
  // white space here --------v
<div class='floatymessage'>\
```

so the newline character is not being escaped.

Off topic, but you should also note that in your `<style>` tag, the word `message` in `.floatymessage` is spelled with an `o`, as in `.floatymessoge`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a space before the `\` escape character. *NOT* :)

```
$j('body').append(" \
            <style type='text/css'> \
                .floatymessoge { \
```

**Edit**: Your code should work without problems. Can you provide a more complete example? I suspect the problem lies elsewhere.